# Export test cases to Excel using QTest API

Tags: java, excel, api, testcase, qtest

I found an API through the QTest backend call for exporting the test cases to Excel.

Ex: https://qtestnet.com/p/11111/portal/testdesign/export/testcase.

But this is not working either through postman or Java. **I feel like this is an internal API, not being exposed to the public.**
Kindly let me know if there is another API for exporting test cases from QTest.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the qTest api to get data and write to excel.

https://github.com/ryan-rs/qtest-swagger-client

It's in python so I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but I have been able to get data from qtest and export to qtest via this api.